# How can I get install the Cool computer language for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, programming

I am considering taking an online class through Coursera.org. The class is offered by Stanford University. They use the [Cool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_%28programming_language%29) programming language. Does anyone have experience installing  Cool in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The installation instructions are [on the coursera wiki page](https://share.coursera.org/wiki/index.php/Compilers:InstallingDirectlyonLinux) (it's very well hidden and took me some time to find).

Note that you *must* install the files where it tells you to, the paths seem to be hardcoded.

@chaskes's answer doesn't work because it's missing the instructions for where to install the files from the tar, as well as some required packages.

Comment: Please avoid giving [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) in the future. The link you've provided is dead now and doesn't contain the installation instructions anymore

Answer (score 1):

According to the "[longer description](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigplan96.ps)" document linked from the [Cool Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_%28programming_language%29) and the [Stanford Compilers course](https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers) page at Coursera, you won't have any trouble running `Cool` on Ubuntu.

> A student distribution of the project is available. These distributions include object code for the coolc reference compiler, assignments, and all documentation.
>   (Source: [Cool main page](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/software/cool/cool.html))

The student distribution appears to be available only as part of a class or on request, so you can wait until you take the class.

As for installing and running:

> Cool is highly portable and easy to install on any Unix machine with standard GNU     software tools gmake, bison, and flex....A separate Linux distribution is made
>   available for students to use on their home PCs. (Source: Cool "[longer description](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigplan96.ps)")

So, again, once you receive the student version you shouldn't have any trouble. You can make sure you have the standard tools installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential flex bison
```

The Stanford course at Coursera says: `Students who choose to do the project can implement it in either C++ or Java.`

If you choose to use Java, you can install the JDK with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: Close voters: This is not OT. It's about doing development on Ubuntu. :)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up and the command line, much appreciated.

Comment: @karel:  Thank you for editing my question, is good to learn. The kindness and focus is also much appreciated.

Comment: Downloaded flex bison as you suggested. As soon as I get Cool to work I'll let you know. I have 2 exams plus homework to do. Thank you for the suggestions, enjoy your day.

Comment: Suggestion did not work. Thus took another class. Thank you for trying.